# passing stdout to two different places?

Tags: python, windows, python-2.7, tkinter, subprocess

The idea is to run the command in the subprocess line, have the entire output sent to one tkinter text widget (outputText) and search the output and if it applies, write info to another tkinter text widget (inputText). See this section of code:

```
if (v1.get()) == 1:
    reply = subprocess.Popen("c:\delprof2\DelProf2.exe /c:" + machineName, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
    data, error = reply.communicate()
    outputText.insert("end", data)
    for line in reply.stdout:
        if line.strip() == "The following user profiles match the deletion criteria:":
        inputText.insert("end", machineName + " has matching profiles" + "\n")
```

and this section:

```
if (v1.get()) == 1:
    reply = subprocess.Popen("c:\delprof2\DelProf2.exe /c:" + machineName, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
    for line in reply.stdout:
        if line.strip() == "The following user profiles match the deletion criteria:":
        inputText.insert("end", machineName + " has matching profiles" + "\n")
    data, error = reply.communicate()
    outputText.insert("end", data)
```

As you can see they're identical except for the order the lines are run. In both examples only the first part of the code will execute, but not the second. It's like the lines are fighting over stdout and whichever runs it first wins!
What do I need to change to have them both work?

Thanks!

Comment: unrelated: use raw string literals for Windows paths: `r"c:\d...\D"` otherwise backslash+char may be interpreted e.g., `"\n"` is a newline (a single character) but `r"\n"` is two characters (backslash + `n`).

Answer (score 1):

Since, as J.F. Sebastian said, .stdout & .communicate() consume the process' stdout, your problem is analogous to using a python generator: you can only get the process' output once.

The solution? If I understand your question correctly, then you just want to use the output of the process twice. In that case, assign it to a variable once and call that variable as many times as you wish. e.g.:

section 1:

```
if (v1.get()) == 1:
  reply = subprocess.Popen(args, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
  data, error = reply.communicate()
  outputText.insert("end", data)
  for line in data:  # the stdout is in data! reply.stdout won't be useful here since you called .communicate()
    # do stuff with data
```

alternatively, in section 2:

```
if (v1.get()) == 1:
  reply = subprocess.Popen(args, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
  data = reply.stdout  # you can call this variable as many times as you want and it will return the same data
  for line in data:
    inputText.insert("end", machineName + " has matching profiles" + "\n")
  # data, error = reply.communicate() <-- this would reset data to ''
  outputText.insert("end", data)
```

Here's an example of data being reset:

```
x = subprocess.Popen("echo ok", stdout=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True)
for line in x.stdout:
  print line
  # this prints "ok", as expected
tup = x.communicate()
tup == ('', None)  # This is True, since x.stdout consumed the output
```

Does that answer your Q?

Comment: 1. `data` is a bytestring in the first example therefore the `for`-loop iterates over *bytes*, not lines: `for byte in data` 2. As said in my answer: calling blocking methods such as `.communicate()` may freeze the GUI if `.communicate()` doesn't return immediately that is why you need threads or async. io here. 3. As said in my answer: you should read *both* streams in the second example otherwise you risk a deadlock.

Comment: Very true & thorough! I was more aiming to address the poster's confusion as to why `data` wasn't returning anything during the second call.

Answer (score 0):

Both code examples are incorrect. Both `for line in process.stdout` and `process.communicate()` consume *all* subprocess' stdout.

Both methods block until the child process is done writing -- it may froze your GUI -- you should either put the code into a separate (from GUI) thread or use asynchronious I/O. Here's code example that shows how to [get subprocess' output using a background thread](https://gist.github.com/zed/42324397516310c86288). Here's [the same using async. I/O (*nix)](https://gist.github.com/zed/9294978).

To insert the output into two places at once, you could modify `update()` method in [the multithreaded code example](https://gist.github.com/zed/42324397516310c86288) to call `.insert()` for each line and widget if necessary.

Note: if you are redirecting both stdout/stderr (as in your code) then you need to read both streams concurrently otherwise a deadlock is possible. If you need stderr then create a separate thread to read (similar to the thread for stdout) or register a read handler with `.createfilehandler()` method (*nix only).

Comment: Thanks for the reply - I thought that was probably the problem.

I don't suppose you could point me to a much simpler example? I'm still very new at this... Thanks.

Comment: @user3514446: if you don't understand something in [my code](https://gist.github.com/zed/42324397516310c86288) then [ask *specific* question](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/278797/4279)

Comment: Did you know that a reply like that to an obvious newbie comes across as elitist and makes you look kind of a jerk? I'm sure that wasn't your intention, but it's hardly welcoming to others who haven't got the experience with python that you do...

Comment: @user3514446: no. I did not know it. And I can't see what is elitist in my answer even after you've mentioned it. It is not my intention to offend you in any way. Is it because I've said that the code examples are incorrect? Don't take it personally — you are not your code — everybody starts somewhere and everybody makes mistakes — there is nothing to be ashamed: learn and fix the code. Software always has bugs even if very experienced people create it. There is a hundred of lines in [code example](https://gist.github.com/zed/42324397516310c86288) — what specific lines do you need explaining?